# How to remove a tr from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html table and I want to remove a complete `<tr>` via jQuery, So I am using following function

```
$("#del_yes").click(function() {
    $("tr#post_".post).remove();
});
```

Please note that **post** is a global javascript variable defined by me, I've tested it by alerting it, And I am getting the expected value of it, which contains the id of a `<tr>` tag like 1, 2 and html is like  `<tr id="post_1">`, `<tr id="post_2">` etc..

So at run time it is supposed to be like `$("tr#post_1").remove();`, `$("tr#post_2").remove();` etc..

I dont know what is getting wrong, I am not able to remove `<tr>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string concatenation is wrong. Use `+` instead of `.`.

```
$("#del_yes").click(function() {
    $("tr#post_" + post).remove();
});
```

Comment: @RayonDabre That's not an issue, assuming the OP is changing the value of `post` globally.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Ooh yes!

Comment: @Mujahed AKAS: too much php I suppose =p
Got same 'errors' from time to time.